# Haskell - Currying? Need further explanation

Tags: haskell, currying, partial-application

So something like

```
addList :: [int] -> int
addList = foldl1 (+)
```

Why does this work? The Currying part. Why no variable?

Comment: @Joren: Actually, through higher-order functions. The OP asked about partial application, now about folds ;) @Matt: Most decent Haskell tutorials I've seen did explain this, although sometimes not instantly. If yours doesn't explain it at all, you might want to switch.

Comment: I understand it when you have pattern matching. Like (((f 6) 7) 8) returns f 6 with a new parameter of 7 and then same thing for 8. in this case say addList [1,2,3,4] is returned, but i just dont know how fold1 gets that list. Like how does haskell know? I know it has to do with currying.

Comment: Sepp2k's explanation is accurate but simple. http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Currying has a more formal explanation.

Comment: @delnan: Well, Matt asked 'why does this work'. My guess was 'this' referred to 'addList', as in 'why does the function addList work'. I agree that interpreting it as 'Why does this definition work' makes more sense though. Next time, I'll just ask for clarification.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you define a function like `f x y = bla`, this is the same as `f x = \y -> bla`, which is the same as `f = \x -> (\y -> bla)`. In other words `f` is a function which takes one argument, `x`, and returns another function which takes one argument, `y`, and then returns the actual result. This is known as currying.

Analogously when you do `f x y`, it's the same as `(f x) y`. I.e. you're calling the function `f` with the argument `x`. This returns another function, which you apply to the argument `y`.

So in other words when you do `addList xs = foldl1 (+) xs`, you're first calling `foldl1 (+)` which then returns another function, which you apply to `xs`. So since the function returned by `foldl1 (+)` is actually the same one as `addList`, you can just shorten it to `addList = foldl1 (+)`.

Answer (score 5):

Besides currying, as sepp2k pointed out, here we use the so called [eta reduction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Eta_conversion). It's one of the reduction rules of lambda calculus which is the basis of Haskell. It says that `\x -> f x` is equivalent to `f` when `x` does not appear in `f`.

Lets apply it to your case. I guess you are comfortable with a definition like `addList xs = foldl1 (+) xs`. We can rewrite this as `addList = \xs -> foldl1 (+) xs` and now applying the eta reduction rule we get `addList = foldl1 (+)`.

This rule is based on the idea that two functions are equal if they give equal results when applied to the same arguments. The two functions here are `f` and `g = \x -> f x` where `f : a -> b` and we want to show that for all `c : a`, `f c = g c`. To prove it take an arbitrary `c : a` and apply it to `g`: `g c = (\x -> f x) c = f c`, the last equality is by another rule called beta reduction which says that function application is evaluated by substitution.

Answer (score 2):

The explanation from sepp2k is correct, I just want to point out (pun intended) that this application of currying has a name: It's called "point-free style". Here is a good explanation, including the pros and cons: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree