# Need help understanding currying

Tags: sml

Here is an example I picked up from this ebook (http://www.cs.cornell.edu/riccardo/prog-smlnj/notes-011001.pdf)

```
-fun curry (f:'a * 'b -> 'c) = fn (x:'a) => fn (y:'b) => f (x,y);
val curry = fn : ('a * 'b -> 'c) -> 'a -> 'b -> 'c
```

How do I interpret this function. Curry takes as argument a function f of type 'a * 'b -> 'c. I can't understand the part after '='. What is the associativity order?

Here is another example:

```
fun add’ (x:int) (y:int):int = x + y;
```

How is this parsed?

Wikipedia says "currying is the technique of transforming a function that takes multiple arguments (or an n-tuple of arguments) in such a way that it can be called as a chain of functions each with a single argument (partial application)". Which is the single argument: the first or the last one out of the multiple arguments?

Comment: I had the same question in haskell. So this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794371/haskell-currying-need-further-explanation

Comment: @Matt: I got more confused after reading it :) Thanks for the link though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fn (x:'a) => fn (y:'b) => f (x,y)` is parsed as `fn (x:'a) => (fn (y:'b) => f (x,y))`. So you have a function, which takes an argument x of type a and returns another function, which takes an argument y of type b. This other function then returns the result of calling `f (x,y)`.

`fun foo x y = ...` is syntactic sugar for `val foo = fn x => fn y => ...`, so again `foo` is a function, which takes one argument x and returns another function, which takes one argument y.

Similarly the call `foo 1 2` will be parsed as `(foo 1) 2`, i.e. it calls the function `foo` with the argument 1 and then calls the resulting function with the argument 2.

Comment: @ sepp2k: I have just started out with SML. Can you please suggest a good resource (book, online material) which I can use.